# SSH connection time out, error 4003 failed to connect to backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

This is my first time deploy wordpress on Google Cloud Platfrom, My website having error 522 after uploaded some jpg image to wordpress.
I failed to connect to ssh, and telnet external & internal ip both return 'connection timeout'.

```
project@cloudshell:~ (project)$ gcloud -v
Google Cloud SDK 307.0.0
alpha 2020.08.21
app-engine-go 1.9.71
app-engine-java 1.9.82
app-engine-python 1.9.91
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.91
beta 2020.08.21
bigtable
bq 2.0.59
cbt 0.9.0
cloud-build-local 0.5.0
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2020.08.21
datalab 20190610
gsutil 4.53
kind 0.7.0
kubectl 1.15.11
minikube 1.12.3
pubsub-emulator 0.1.0
skaffold 1.13.1
project@cloudshell:~ (project)$ service ssh status
[ ok ] sshd is running.
project@cloudshell:~ (project)$
```

```
project@cloudshell:~ (project)$ service --status-all
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  cgroupfs-mount
 [ - ]  cron
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ + ]  docker
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lxc
 [ ? ]  lxc-net
 [ - ]  postgresql
 [ - ]  procps
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  supervisor
 [ + ]  udev
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

I tried restart the vm instances multiple times and increase the machine memory but still no luck.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem or how to debug?

*UPDATE

I just found when i type systemctl in google shell, it return `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`, does it matters? I'm new to this

Comment: Did you use the correct IP address?

Comment: @MichaelHampton u mean the external ip? Im sure i using the correct one.

Comment: Did you check to ensure that it did not change?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it changed after i reboot the instances, i update all the dns setting on gcp and cloudflare

Comment: Hmm. You should consider making your external IP address persistent.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get when trying to connect to your instance for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

-- Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed

-- Code: 4003

-- Reason: failed to connect to backend

Please check official documentation on [Failed to connect to backend](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#failed_to_connect_to_backend) from troubleshooting SSH.

> These errors occur when you try to use SSH to connect to a VM that doesn't have a public IP address and for which you haven't configured Identity-Aware Proxy on port 22.

To resolve this issue [Create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) on port 22 that allows ingress traffic from Identity-Aware Proxy.